# popViewController and then immediately present an alert controller

Tags: navigation, uinavigationcontroller, uialertcontroller, popviewcontroller, uialertviewcontroller

I'm trying to pop the controller from an alert action and getting to another view controller. I want to do some action immediately after I get on to this other controller, say open another alert controller. How do I do it?

```
UIAlertController.getAlertView("Success", message: "Your password has been successfully changed!", cancelButtonTitle: "Ok", cancelHandler: { (action) in
 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                        }).show(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back to previous viewController on click of alert action then below code will help you.

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Your password has been successfully changed!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: { action in
        //perfoem any action you want on click of OK
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```